# Accessing fields from the values of a Map in Kotlin fails

Tags: kotlin, class, dictionary, oop

I am having the following two classes:

```
class A() {
  val name = "A"
}
class B() {
  val name = "B"
}
```

Then I create a map with instances of those two classes as values of the Map.

```
var m = mapOf("1" to A(), "2" to B())
```

Then I try to access the field `name` from the values of this map.

```
for ((k, v) in m) {
     println(v.name)
}
```

And I get this error:

```
error: unresolved reference: name
    println(v.name)
```

How do I access the field, and why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first you need to know that map contains a key and a value and each one must have a type for example: (`Map<String, Int>` so the key must be a string and the value must be an Int).

Now for you case the map is: `var m = mapOf("1" to A(), "2" to B())`
the key is of type `String` but the value is of type `A` in the first element and of type `B` in the second element, so the compiler will specify the type `Any` to the value so your map is of type: `Map<String, Any>`, that's why when you try to access `v.name` you can't because in type `Any` there nothing called `name`.

To fix this problem you can use inheritance, you can create an interface:

```
interface X {
    val name: String
}

class A(): X {
    override val name = "A"
}
class B(): X {
    override val name = "B"
}
```

So now your map will be of type `Map<String, X>` because both `A` and `B` are of type `X` and you will be able to get access to `name`

Answer (score 3):

Because you map to two different classes it can only conclude that you are mapping to the class `Any` which is the only class they both share, which doesn't have the field `name`. To solve it you can let both classes implement a common interface, like this

```
interface HasName {
    val name : String
}

class A : HasName {
    override val name = "A"
}
class B  : HasName {
    override val name = "B"
}
```

After this the compiler recognizes that you are mapping to objects that implement `HasName` and your code will work fine